# How to open calendar view when click on "search more" option of Many2one field for Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, many-to-one, calendarview

I want to open calendar view in many2one field "Search More" option. For this, in XML I applied calendar view reference in many2one field. But, didn't get required result.

Thanks in advance.

```xml
<record id="view_partner_fare_well_ser_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">fare.well.room.ser.calendar</field>
<field name="model">fare.well.room.ser</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <calendar string="Farewell Room" color="status" date_start="cere_start_date">
        <field name="room"/>
        <field name="cere_start_date"/>
        <field name="cere_end_date"/>
        <field name="status"/>
    </calendar>
</field>
```

```xml
<field name="ceremonial_room"
       context="{'calendar_view_ref': 'P2N_Sales.view_partner_fare_well_ser_calendar'}"
       options="{'limit': 1, 'no_open': True, 'no_create': True, 'no_create_edit': True}"/>
```